# IIS 7 Url Rewrite Rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis-7

I want to rewrite an existing url `/rss/content.aspx?id=4878` to display as `/rss`.

I also need requests to `/rss` to display this same content. I have this rule:

```
<rule name="ContentRSS">
   <match url="^rss$" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="rss/content.aspx?id=4878" />
</rule>
```

but it doesn't rewrite requests to `rss/content.aspx?id=4878` as `/rss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rule should be:

```
<rules>
   <rule name="ContentRSS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^rss/content.aspx$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="/rss" appendQueryString="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=4878" />
            </conditions>
    </rule>
    <rule name="ContentRSS rrewrite">
        <match url="^rss$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/rss/content.aspx?id=4878" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

This rule will **rewrite** `/rss` to `/rss/content.aspx?id=4878`. And when you will try to open in browser `rss/content.aspx?id=4878` it will **redirect** to `/rss`